# How to select unique rows (comparing by a few columns)?

Tags: sql

I want to select unique rows from a table (without repeating the combination of 'f' and 'x' fields).

The table:

```
| f | x | z |
|---|—--|---|
| 1 | 1 | a |
| 1 | 2 | b |
| 1 | 3 | c |
| 1 | 3 | d |
```

The result:

```
| f | x | z |
|---|—--|---|
| 1 | 1 | a |
| 1 | 2 | b |
```

Comment: why did (f,x)=(1,3) disappear? is it that when there a re more than one occurence of this couple we should ignore ALL occurrences of that?

Comment: Yes, if (f, x) is not unique (more than one), we should ignore all occurrences of that.

Comment: If an answer resolved your issue, you can mark it as the correct answer by clicking the check mark icon next to it. This will help others who may have the same question in the future.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following query groups rows in "the_table" by "f" and "x", selects the minimum value of "z" in each group and filters out groups with a count greater than 1, returning only unique combinations of "f" and "x".

```
SELECT f, x, MIN(z) AS z
FROM the_table
GROUP BY f, x
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
WITH
  check_repetitions AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY f, x)   AS repetitions
  FROM
    your_table
)
SELECT
  f, x, z
FROM
  check_repetitions
WHERE
  repetitions = 1
```

Comment: I took this same approach but realize that grouping by f,x and using a min or max on z gets the necessary result without the cte

Comment: @ClearlyClueless Just because I didn't answer with that doesn't mean I don't understand it, I just didn't see the point in replicating someone else's answer after I realised.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following query to select only rows where the combination of columns f and x do not repeat:

```
SELECT f, x, MIN(z) AS z
FROM table_name
GROUP BY f, x
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

This query will group the rows based on the values of f and x, and then return only the rows where the combination of f and x occurs only once. The function MIN is used to select a single value for z for each group.

Comment: This varies from @andreasviolaris answer, how?

Comment: It didnt at all, i was running the code to make sure about the results on sqlize. online, by the time i posted here there were already the answer hehe.

Anyways i hope you got the results.